# Use uislider to control alpha in uitextview

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uislider, alpha

How can I use `uislider` to control `alpha` in `uitextview`?
Please provide code.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear @zeropt7 - you seem pretty new here. Generally when you ask a question here, it's good form to show us that you've tried to figure this out for yourself first. You can do that by telling us the things you've tried, and where it became a problem for you. That will also help us to narrow down what is the actual problem you're having, and give you better answers, so it's a good idea for you too.

Comment: @TarynEast I've tried to search the code but can't find any. If you have read my previous questions I do always provide codes that I've tried. This time I am really helpless, without clue for which keyword to search for to know which method I should be using.

Comment: Then what you need to tell us is "I tried searching on keywords X and Y and Z and couldn't find anything. Then I tried searching the docs at *site*" etc etc... just something to show us you've also put in the effort that you clearly have :) No, I haven't read your previous questions - and just a tip: most people don't go and look at the posters other questions, they just try to answer this one... so every question must seem good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some class with instance variables `_yourTextView` and `_yourSlider`, use:

```
_yourSlider.minimumValue = 0;
_yourSlider.maximumValue = 1;
_yourSlider.value = 0.0;
[_yourSlider  addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then, in the same class, define function:

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    _yourTextView.alpha = sender.value;
}
```

The definition of UISlider and UITextView,i believe, you can do by yourself.